# How can I say in this situation (buying a top-up card)?

Tags: expressions

When I buy a top up card (to recharge the phone balance ), I usually say " can I get Maxis(the company's name i use) 30$ card" but I dont know either its correct expression or not. should I say "maxis card worth of 30$"?

what would native speakers say in this situation.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The most natural expression would be "Please can I have/get a $30 Maxis card?".